# document.querySelectorAll() doesn't work as expected in a Greasemonkey 3.11 script in Firefox 54.0.1

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, selectors-api

The relevant part of my script as [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        mcve
// @namespace   gb
// @include     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

// this is the one I'm really interested in: the tag entered into SE's tag editor field
let es = document.querySelectorAll('span.post-tag.rendered-element')
console.debug(es)

es = document.querySelectorAll('span.post-tag')
console.debug(es)

es = document.querySelectorAll('span.rendered-element')
console.debug(es)
```

The resulting output in FF's Web Console:

*`NodeList`*`[  ]`

*`NodeList`*`[`*`<span.post-tag>`*`]` ← Not the one I'm interested in

*`NodeList`*`[  ]`

If I enter the following in Firebug's search field:

- `span.post-tag.rendered-element` → finds the one I'm interested in
- `span.post-tag` → finds two, the one also found in the code above and the one I'm interested in
- `span.rendered-element` → finds the one I'm interested in

which is all as expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Probably need to wait for javascript to load the elements.  Use `waitForKeyElements` or similar.

Comment: @BrockAdams That's it! Thanks! If I surround my mcve with e.g. `window.setTimeout(function () { ... }, 5000)` all are found. If you make this an answer I'm going to accept it.

Comment: You're welcome, but this Q is more of a duplicate.  I'm just too lazy, anymore, to hunt down the refs to close it. ;)

Comment: @BrockAdams, There are a variety of possibilities. My go-to dup-target for waiting for DOM changes is: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2844565), but that covers how to detect changes, not necessarily why you need to wait. OTH, once mentioned Gerold has understood that it's necessary, so that explanation doesn't appear needed.